# Create a function in Oracle with sysdate

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would really appreciate som help with creating a function i oracle sql! The function is supposed to return sysdate in form of 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI'!
This is what I came up with, but will not work

```
    Create function get_återdatum return number as
    NU varchar2(20)NOT NULL;
    Begin
    SELECT to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI') into NU from DUAL;
    Return(NU);
    End;
    /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax is

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_återdatum RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  NU varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI') INTO NU FROM DUAL;
  RETURN NU;
END;
/
```

`IS` instead of `AS`, `NOT NULL` is unnecessary (actually requiring you to init the variable), `()` in return statement is unnecessary, and also you want to return `VARCHAR2` instead of `number`, and lastly - you might want to consider `CREATE OR REPLACE` instead of plain `CREATE`

EDIT: as @nop77svk pointed out, you can omit the select completely and simply do

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_återdatum RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI');
END;
/
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much :-D That gave the right output

Comment: @SaraReimertz, no problem, if an answer helped you resolve your problem, consider marking it as accepted to make it clear that your question is answered, thanks

Comment: @radoh, consider removing the select from dual and doing the date to string conversion simply in PL/SQL.

Comment: @nop77svk thanks for the suggestion, I've edited it in